# A question about FlatList renderItem Component performance and memory usage

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm a `react-native` newbie.
Just a question about `FlatList` `renderItem` `Component` performance and memory usage.

Which of below `renderItem` `Component`s is faster in performance and which is memory friendly for a large list?

1:

```
class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{width: '100%', height: 60}}>
       {
         this.props.size ===  30 ?
         (
           <View style={{width: 30, height: 30}}>
                <Text>test</Text>
           </View>
         )
         :
         null
       }
       <View>...</View>
     </View>
    )
  }
}
```

2:

```
class MyListItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
         <View style={{width: '100%', height: 60}}>
           <View style={{width: this.props.size, height: this.props.size}}>
                <Text>test</Text>
           </View>
           <View>...</View>
         </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Second is faster and memory-friendly because it will not check any condition, so its performance is faster compared to first. 
 You can use FlatList it's better than both.